# Compare the results of two tables using foreach

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I have two tables in database and I want to use the result of ist table and compare it with 2nd table, like:

```
// we connect to example.com and port 3307
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pass123") or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db("PhGateway") or die(mysql_error()); 
$result = mysql_query("select mtMsgId from SMS where SMS.`result` = '0' ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

$mtMsgid=$row['mtMsgId'];

}
```

I want to compare and then display the result of `$mtMsgid` with another table
the other table name is DN and has two fields `mtMsgId` and `msgStatus`
like:

```
select * from DN where mtMsgId = 'the whole above result'
```

Comment: 1. Make $mtMsgid an Array. 2. Use `IN()`: `'select * from DN where mtMsgId IN('.implode(',', $mtMsgid).')'` 3. Or use `JOIN`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a JOIN. You can do this in SQL:

`$result = mysql_query("select s.mtMsgId,j.msgStatus from JN j, SMS s WHERE s.mtMsgId = j.mtMsgId AND s.result = '0' ");`

This names two tables to get data from, "SMS" as s and "JN" as j. You 'synchronize' the results with the s.mtMsgId = j.mtMsgId (marry them up according to their mtMsgIds) and you are interested in results for which SMS.result is 0.